# What is the right place to put custom logic in JPOS?

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, iso8583, jpos

I am working in a project where a **request(ISO 8583)** need to be send via **JPOS server** to the backed (Remote Host as per official doc)  via SOAP api.

We have implemented our system as follows:

[image]

We implemented a ISOListner in a middle ware(spring boot project) where it converts the **incoming ISO message** to SOAP request.

Is it possible to embed the Middle ware code to JPOS server itself and omit the mw?

If possible , what is the right place to put our conversion logic ? 
Is it the **ChannelAdaptor** or **TransactionManager** ?

Few blogs suggest that we can put all logic to TransactionManager or ChannelAdaptor. If it is true 
then **why we need mux and channel** at all? Or our architecture is ok to proceed further ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of completeness I will include the answer to this question that was also asked in jPOS Users group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jpos-users/PGzb4syQRzs):

> We usually implement a custom participant doing the SOAP/REST thing.
>
> In the case of REST, we use Apache's HTTP Client
>   (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.5) that provides a nice
>   async interface that works great with the TransactionManager's PAUSE.
>
> Here is an example:

```
public int prepare (long id, Serializable o) {
        Context ctx = (Context) o;
        String url = getURL (ctx);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(ctx.getString(JSON_REQUEST.name()),ContentType.create("application/json", Consts.UTF_8));
        post.setEntity(entity);

        try {
            client.execute(post, response -> {
                int sc = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (sc == HttpStatus.SC_CREATED || sc == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
                    ctx.put (JSON_RESPONSE.name(), EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
                ctx.resume();
                return null;
            });
            return PREPARED | PAUSE | NO_JOIN | READONLY;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            warn (e);
        }
        return ABORTED;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

TransactionManager is the right place to add custom logic. I guess your are using mux and channel to send iso message to MW socket listener component. Which can be avoided by using a middleware like rabbitmq to connect to backend servers.

For example isomessage in transaction manager can be converted to json and send it to backend server using mq.